# Postgres - aggregate user events by session

Tags: sql, postgresql, time-series

I have a table with events that looks like this: ID, USER_ID, CREATED_AT, EVENT_NAME.

I am trying to get the sequence of events users usually create in a session. A new session starts when a user event is more than 5 minutes apart from the last one.

I went as far as being able to create a view that has this info:

[image]

Reading the table in that order, every time "TIME_DIFF" is greater than 5min a new session starts.

How can I now aggregate the events by session so that in the end I have something like this?

[image]

Follow below the table, the views and some test data:

```
CREATE SCHEMA test;

CREATE TABLE test."TRACKING_EVENTS" (
    "ID" serial PRIMARY key,
    "USER_ID" text,
    "CREATED_AT" TIMESTAMP,
    "EVENT_NAME" text
);

CREATE VIEW
    test."ORDERED_EVENTS"
AS
    SELECT 
        "ID", 
        "USER_ID", 
        "CREATED_AT" AS "EVENT_TIME", 
        "EVENT_NAME",
        CASE WHEN 
            lag("CREATED_AT", 1) OVER (ORDER BY "USER_ID", "CREATED_AT") < "CREATED_AT" 
        THEN 
            lag("CREATED_AT", 1) OVER (ORDER BY "USER_ID", "CREATED_AT")
        ELSE
            NULL 
        END AS "PREVIOUS_EVENT_TIME" 
    FROM 
        test."TRACKING_EVENTS";

CREATE VIEW
    test."ORDERED_EVENTS_WITH_DIFF"
AS
    SELECT  
        "ID", 
        "USER_ID", 
        "EVENT_TIME", 
        "EVENT_NAME",
        "PREVIOUS_EVENT_TIME",
        "EVENT_TIME" - "PREVIOUS_EVENT_TIME" AS "TIME_DIFF"
    FROM 
        test."ORDERED_EVENTS";

-- Period 1
INSERT INTO test."TRACKING_EVENTS" ("ID", "USER_ID", "CREATED_AT", "EVENT_NAME") 
VALUES (1, 'user1', '2019-1-1 01:00:00'::timestamp, 'EVENT_1');
INSERT INTO test."TRACKING_EVENTS" ("ID", "USER_ID", "CREATED_AT", "EVENT_NAME") 
VALUES (3, 'user1', '2019-1-1 01:00:05'::timestamp, 'EVENT_2');
INSERT INTO test."TRACKING_EVENTS" ("ID", "USER_ID", "CREATED_AT", "EVENT_NAME") 
VALUES (5, 'user1', '2019-1-1 01:00:10'::timestamp, 'EVENT_3');

INSERT INTO test."TRACKING_EVENTS" ("ID", "USER_ID", "CREATED_AT", "EVENT_NAME") 
VALUES (2, 'user2', '2019-1-1 01:00:01'::timestamp, 'EVENT_1');
INSERT INTO test."TRACKING_EVENTS" ("ID", "USER_ID", "CREATED_AT", "EVENT_NAME") 
VALUES (4, 'user2', '2019-1-1 01:00:06'::timestamp, 'EVENT_2');
INSERT INTO test."TRACKING_EVENTS" ("ID", "USER_ID", "CREATED_AT", "EVENT_NAME") 
VALUES (6, 'user2', '2019-1-1 01:00:11'::timestamp, 'EVENT_3');

-- Period 2
INSERT INTO test."TRACKING_EVENTS" ("ID", "USER_ID", "CREATED_AT", "EVENT_NAME") 
VALUES (7, 'user1', '2019-1-1 01:10:00'::timestamp, 'EVENT_1');
INSERT INTO test."TRACKING_EVENTS" ("ID", "USER_ID", "CREATED_AT", "EVENT_NAME") 
VALUES (9, 'user1', '2019-1-1 01:10:05'::timestamp, 'EVENT_2');
INSERT INTO test."TRACKING_EVENTS" ("ID", "USER_ID", "CREATED_AT", "EVENT_NAME") 
VALUES (11, 'user1', '2019-1-1 01:10:10'::timestamp, 'EVENT_3');

INSERT INTO test."TRACKING_EVENTS" ("ID", "USER_ID", "CREATED_AT", "EVENT_NAME") 
VALUES (8, 'user2', '2019-1-1 01:10:01'::timestamp, 'EVENT_1');
INSERT INTO test."TRACKING_EVENTS" ("ID", "USER_ID", "CREATED_AT", "EVENT_NAME") 
VALUES (10, 'user2', '2019-1-1 01:10:06'::timestamp, 'EVENT_2');
INSERT INTO test."TRACKING_EVENTS" ("ID", "USER_ID", "CREATED_AT", "EVENT_NAME") 
VALUES (12, 'user2', '2019-1-1 01:10:11'::timestamp, 'EVENT_3');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
select user_id, session,
       array_agg(event_name order by created_at)
from (select tt.*,
             count(*) filter (where prev_ca < created_at - interval '5 minute') over (partition by user_id order by created_at) as session
      from (select tt.*,
                   lag(created_at) over (partition by user_id order by CREATED_AT) as prev_ca
            from test."TRACKING_EVENTS" tt
           ) tt
     ) tt
group by user_id, session
order by user_id, session;
```

Note that this uses `array_agg()` rather than `string_agg()`.  You are using Postgres, so `array_agg()` is a good way to combine multiple values together.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had to adjust the query a little bit because of a problem that was happening with the last user session. It as either grouping the last two sessions together  or creating an extra one with only one event. This is the change I did:

`select tt.*,
         lag("CREATED_AT") over (order by "USER_ID", "CREATED_AT") as prev_ca
         from test."TRACKING_EVENTS" tt`

Comment: @FelipeTaiarol . . . I think that should be `partition by user_id order by created_at)`.